# When my activity recreates TextInputEditText all methods (beforeTextChanged, onTextChanged, afterTextChanged ) called pointlessly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext, android-dark-theme

I change the darkTheme as follows in the SettingsFragment under MainActivity and MainActivity is recreated normally. However, when I return to the MainFragment later, all the methods in the TextInputEditText are called meaninglessly. How can I prevent this?

SettingsFragment

```
var sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mode", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
var isNightMode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("nightmode",false)

with(binding){

  if (isNightMode)
     darkThemeSwitch.isChecked = true
     
     darkThemeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->

          if (b){
             AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
             sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("nightmode",true).apply()
          } else {
             AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
             sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("nightmode",false).apply()
          }

   }

}
```

The TextInputEditText I meant above is written as searchBarEditText below.

MainFragment

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(){

    private var _binding : FragmentMainBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val placeList = arrayListOf<Place>()
    private var placesAdapter : PlacesAdapter? = null
    private val TAG = "TRVL_MainFragment"
    private lateinit var db : FirebaseFirestore
    private var kullaniciAdi = ""
    private var email = ""
    private var userUid = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        val view = binding.root

        return view
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Log.i(TAG,"onViewCreated")

        initializeFirebaseTools()
        createRecyclerView()
        settings()
        getPlaces()

    }

    private fun settings() {

        val settingsButton = headerView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.settingsButton)

        settingsButton.setOnClickListener {
            binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToSettingsFragment()
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
        }

    }


    private fun initializeFirebaseTools() {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        userUid = mAuth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
    }

    private fun createRecyclerView() {

        Log.i(TAG,"createRecyclerView and Adapter")

        placesAdapter = PlacesAdapter(placeList)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = placesAdapter
    }

    private fun getPlaces() {

        Log.i(TAG,"getPlaces")


        var collectionTAG = ""

        when(localeCode){
            "tr" -> collectionTAG = "Places"
            "en" -> collectionTAG = "PlacesEng"
            else -> collectionTAG = "Places"
        }

        db.collection(collectionTAG).addSnapshotListener { value, error ->

            if (error != null){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Error: " + error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {

                if (value != null){

                    Log.i(TAG,"value is not null")

                    if (!value.isEmpty){

                        Log.i(TAG,"value is not Empty")

                        placeList.clear()
                        val documents = value.documents

                        for (document in documents){

                            val name  = document.getString("name")
                            val desc = document.getString("desc")
                            val photos = document.get("photos") as ArrayList<String>?
                            val placeId = document.getString("placeId")
                            val productId = document.getString("productId")

                            if (name != null && desc != null && !photos.isNullOrEmpty() && placeId != null && productId != null){
                                val place = Place(name,desc,photos,placeId,productId)
                                placeList.add(place)
                                Log.i(TAG,"placeList -> " + placeList.size)
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG,"one of the parameters is null")
                            }

                        }

                        placesAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        binding.searchBarEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

                Log.i(TAG,"beforeTextChanged: " + charSequence.toString())
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

                Log.i(TAG,"onTextChanged: " + charSequence.toString())
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {

                val text = editable.toString()
                Log.i(TAG,"afterTextChanged: " + text)
                placesAdapter?.filter(text)

            }
        })

    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

Comment: The behavior you are observing is likely due to the recreation of the MainFragment upon a theme change which triggers a new lifecycle event sequence, causing the TextWatcher methods to be called as searchBarEditText is being re-initialized.

Comment: It can re-initialized but re-initialization doesnt means that calls all methods of this. When it initializes in firstly creating in MainFragment, no methods call in this TextWatcher